# Print on html page data from .js file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm very new to the whole server job and I'm trying to do this thing by myself. Basically I have a server written in js with express and I'm trying to print something on my html page, sent from the server.

```
var app = require('express')();

var bodyParser = requires('body-parser');
app.use( bodyParser.json() );
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded( {
    extended: true;
}))
app.use(express.json());

var server = app.listen('7777');
console.log("It's on, m8!");

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send("Sunny Filadelphia! ");
})
```

So I want "Sunny Filadelphia" to appear on my html page. Is there a specific tutorial I should look at? Or a specific method to call on my xmlhttp variable? I'm really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to use a template language to insert content into HTML that you've already got. [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) and [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) are both popular options for Node.

Then, once you have them properly setup (they're both well-documented), you can

```
res.render('index', {
   myString: "Sunny Filadelphia! "
});
```

And, with Jade, for instance:

```
div#putMyContentHere = myString
```

Alternatively, you can return the data asynchronously using AJAX. On the server:

```
app.get('/data', function (req,res) {
   res.send("Sunny Filadelphia! ");
});
```

And client side with jQuery:

```
$.get('/data', function (data) {
    $("#myDiv").append(data);
});
```

Comment: I can't do it with Ajax and nothing else?

Comment: You can, but if you want to take the best approach based on the use-case you described, templates is it.

Comment: I want to use the simplest method without using too many tools, I'm really new at it

Answer (score -1):

Look at the File System API in node.js docs: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

I'd look into the writeFile method in node.js.

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile('index.html', 'Stuff to write', function (err) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log('Saved!');
});
```

Comment: Writing to a file should not be equated with serving a dynamic file.

Comment: i was under the assumption he wanted to write to an html file.

Comment: No, I want the messege to appear on my web page, not in my html file